# git push error while push to remote repository

Tags: git, github, version-control

We are new to Git and planning to create local repository in windows and share between team through LAN. We have followed following steps and facing issue while push the repository to other.

Created new folder D:/Git/Repository and shared the Git folder to team member using windows file sharing option.

```
$ cd d:/Git/Repository

$ git init

Initialized empty Git repository in d:/git/Repository/.git/

user@host /d/git/Repository (master)
```

Added new file (Readme.txt) into the repository location

```
$ git add Readme.txt

user@host /d/git/Repository (master)

$ git commit -a -m 'Added Readme'

[master (root-commit) f072a76] Added Readme
 1 file changed, 14 insertions(+)
create mode 100644 Readme.txt
user@host /d/git/Repository (master)
```

Again initialized repository with –bare option
    $ git --bare init

```
Initialized empty Git repository in d:/git/Repository/

user@host /d/git/Repository (master)
```

Added to remote

```
$ git remote add origin file:////host/D/Git/Repository

user@host /d/git/Repository (master)
```

Try to push the changes into other repository, getting some fatal error

```
$ git push origin master

fatal: '//host/D/Git/Repository' does not appear to be a git repository

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

user@host /d/git/Repository (master)
```

Comment: Are you shure you using the correct  path to your remote repo, "/host/D/Git/Repository", I mean, it's on the file system, should not be to Github?

Comment: Yes, We don't want to share file in Github. We want to share between our LAN so that path has been used as file system.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid re-initialize an repo with a working directory (git internal files will be mixed up with your project files) and you should avoid having a working tree in a "remote" repo.

In this case git fails to find `//host/D/Git/Repository` on your filesystem.

Assuming you already have a project prepared on Github:

```
$ git clone <url to project on Github> c:/Git/Repository
$ git add Readme.txt
$ git commit -a -m 'Added Readme'
$ git fetch origin
$ git push origin master
```

You should not share this private local repo with other developers.

If you need a shared repo on the file system (assuming "d:" is a shared disc):

```
$ cd d:/git/sharedrepo
$ git init --bare --shared
```

Each developer then clone the shared repo into private local repo:

```
$ git clone d:/git/sharedrepo c:/git/myrepo
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, We don't want to create any web hosted Respository, We want to share share inside our LAN. So that I have created repository as shared (as per your recommendation) and tried same error getting.

Comment: @Mahesh, what is the output if run `git remote -v`?

Comment: $ git remote -v

origin  file:////host/D/Git/Repository (fetch)

origin  file:////host/D/Git/Repository (push)

Comment: Can you do `ls //host/D/Git/Repository` (you may need to replace `ls` with a suitable command) ?